# why my mail is sent more than once?

Tags: php, email

I've developed some php code, which sends a mail to some users registered in my database.
The problem is that, when I execute this script through the navigator, it loads a lot of time, and I have to stop the loading through the X button of navigator ( in my case with google chrome ).
The mail is sent more than once, and I dont know why.

I have this code:

```
global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_premios");

foreach ( $blogs as $blog ) {
    $to = $blog->email;

    if( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ) == true ){
        echo "Mail sent properly";
    }
}
```

which uses API of WordPress.

NOTE: I have sent this mail to myself, and it's sent properly, only once, but when I do with the code above, the problem comes.
I have 600 users that it is not a big number.

What I think is that the script loose the connection with database, and it tries to reconnect, and the mail is resent....I don't find another cause for it.

I hope your help.
Thanks very much, Daniel

Comment: You know your mail-sent-snippet is into a `foreach()` loop right?

Comment: yes, is any problem with it?

Comment: Every iteration of the loop it is trying to sent an email, so for the number of records in the database in the `wp_premios` table, it is sending an email.

Comment: @sanki Could it be your caps-lock key is stuck?

Comment: @RichardBernards Wouldn't that be his shift key?

Comment: BANG ON TARGET @RichardBernards

Comment: Yes, it's what I want, to send the mail to all the users

Comment: But the problem is that the mail is sent to the same user more than once

Comment: @DanielGarciaSanchez Did you already check to see if the same users exist multiple times in the table wp_premios ?

Comment: Yes, and they don't exist more than once

Comment: Does exist the posibility of to loose the connection with mysql, and rerun the script itself?

Answer (score 0):

According to Wordpress [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail), wp_mail's $to parameter can be string or array, which means that you could store the email addresses in an array and after the loop ends, you can use that array as $to.

The problem with that solution is that all the users that will read that email will see all the other email addresses. In order to circumvent that, you could use the [Bcc header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy), something like:

```
$headers = array();

foreach ($blogs as $blog) {
    $headers[] = 'Bcc: '. $blog->email;
}

wp_mail('you@example.com', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

As a side note, you could select only the email field from DB, since it is the only one that you use.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem once, and it was because I was including the `wp-blog-header` twice. It was a plugin in fact, but it was solved by just changing require to `require_once()` - Since the blog-header sums up all wp hooks and functions, all of then are fired twice

Hope it helps ;)